# Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation for pairwise interactions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spin-models, mean-field-theory

Consider a (classical) Potts-like model in which $N$ 'spins' can take on $Q$ distinct states; let $x_i$ be the state of the $i$th spin.
The energy of a particular configuration is,
$$
H = -\sum_{i<j} \sum_{\mu = 1}^M \xi_i^\mu (x_i)\xi_{j}^\mu (x_j),
$$
where $\sum_{i<j}$ represents a sum over all distinct pairs of spins.
If the Hamiltonian instead had a summation over all indices,
$$
H' = -\sum_{i,j} \sum_{\mu = 1}^M \xi_i^\mu (x_i)\xi_{j}^\mu (x_j),
$$
one could apply the Hubbard–Stratonovich transformation to introduce auxiliary fields, $\phi_\mu$:
$$
p(\{x_i\})
=
\frac{1}{Z}
\exp
\left(
\beta
\sum_{i,j} \sum_{\mu=1}^M \xi_i^\mu (x_i)\xi_{j}^\mu (x_j).
\right)
\propto
\int \prod_{\mu=1}^M
\mathrm d \phi_\mu \, 
\exp
\left(
-
\frac{1}{4\beta}
\sum_{\mu=1}^M
\phi_\mu^2
+
\sum_{\mu=1}^M \sum_i \xi_i^\mu(x_i) \phi_\mu
\right).
$$
Doing so facilitates mean-field analysis and makes Monte Carlo sampling significantly easier when the integrand is seen as (proportional to) a joint probability distribution for $x_i$ and $\phi_\mu$.
Is such a technique only possible when using a summation over all indices (Hamiltonian $H'$) or can it be modified/extended to use when only summing over pairs of spins (Hamiltonian $H$)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this for a bit, and I've come up with an answer to my own question. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Observe that,
$$
\sum_{i,j} \sum_{\mu=1}^M\xi_i^\mu(x_i) \xi_j^\mu(x_j) = 
2\sum_{i<j} \sum_{\mu=1}^M\xi_i^\mu(x_i) \xi_j^\mu(x_j)
+
\sum_{i} \sum_{\mu=1}^M\left(\xi_i^\mu(x_i) \right)^2.
$$

Therefore, for the Hamiltonian $H$,
$$
p(\{x_i\})
=
\frac{1}{Z}
\exp\left(
\frac{\beta}{2}
\sum_{i,j}\sum_{\mu=1}^M \xi_i^\mu(x_i) \xi_j^\mu(x_j)
\right)
\exp\left(
-
\frac{\beta}{2}
\sum_i \sum_{\mu=1}^M \left(\xi_i^\mu(x_i)\right)^2
\right)
\\
\propto
\int \prod_{\mu=1}^M \mathrm d \phi_\mu \, 
\exp
\left(
-\frac{1}{2\beta}
\sum_{\mu = 1}^M \phi_\mu^2
+
\sum_{\mu=1}^M \sum_i \left[
\xi_i^\mu(x_i) \phi_\mu 
-
\frac{\beta}{2}
\left(\xi_i^\mu(x_i)\right)^2
\right]
\right).
$$
The form of the integrand has all the usual advantages associated with the Hubbard–Stratonovich transformation; in particular, when viewed as a joint probability distribution for $\{x_i\}$ and $\{\phi_\mu\}$, the distributions for $\{x_i\}$ conditioned on $\{\phi_\mu\}$ and $\{\phi_\mu\}$ conditioned on $\{x_i\}$ can be written as products of independent distributions for each component of $\{x_i\}$ or $\{\phi_\mu\}$.

Please let me know if you spot any errors in this approach or have any additional comments.